# How to use ssh tunneling for remote web server

Tags: ssh, tunneling

I have my `localhost`, `gateway`, `remote web server`.  I cannot access `remote web server` from `localhost`.

Is there an `ssh tunneling` command which I can run `only` on my localhost which would provide me access to the `remote web server` on port 8080? anything like

`ssh -L 8080:gateway:*`

(what I wish for every request going to localhost 8080 make it as if the request was made on gateway and return the result to me, all this without opening a new port in addition to 22 on the remote gateway).

thanks

Comment: Have you tried `ssh gateway -L 8080:remote-web-server:8080`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ssh access to your gateway, following command should do what you describe:

```
ssh gateway -L 8080:webserver:8080 -N
```

This will ask you for gateway password and "hang" until you kill it with Ctrl+C.